# skin for channels connected to ms bot framework

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, bots, facebook-chatbot

I developed a bot using MS Bot Framework. I have been using it as a web chat(iframe) as well as in the facebook channel. I want to customize skin of all the channels, including web chat. I came accross the following:

https://www.channels.elastacloud.com/channels/disruptive-ai/custom-styling-of-the-microsoft-bot-framework

With this I can change the skin of my web chat(iframe) one. But how can I apply the skin to the facebook channel. Is there any way to do that ? I have deployed the bot to MS Azure.

Thanks

Comment: No you can't. You can customize web chat because you can provide a custom build yourself. For other channels the UI of the channel is provided by the respective channel's organization.

Answer (score 0):

[WebChat Customization tutorial](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/)

The above link provides insight and directions on how to customize the skin for Web Chat (via DirectLine). Unfortunately, this is the only channel that allows customization for your bot.